# Under what conditions is $||x|-|y|| = |x-y|$ true?

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-value

Given that $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, when is the inverse triangle inequality an equality?

$$||x|-|y|| = |x-y|$$

Comment: What do you think? There aren't that many cases to consider...

Comment: Hint: Square both sides and see which conditions hold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose they're equal. This is equivalent to their squares being equal (as both numbers are nonnegative):
$$
x^2-2|xy|+y^2=x^2-2xy+y^2
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
|xy|=xy
$$

Answer (score 1):

Only when $x$ and $y$ have the same sign. This is obvious by considering the four possible cases.